# Approaches to Creating Screen Capture Functionality on a Web Page

Tags: java, javascript, flash, screen-capture

I have read the various posts here on SO regarding screen capturing, but none seem to be answering my situation.

On our website (inside a web page), essentially here is what I would like to be able to do.

1. User clicks on a 'capture region of screen' button
2. They get some sort of draggable/sizable box they can use to define the area to capture
3. the captured area gets converted into a (preferrably) .png
4. image is uploaded (or at least made available to upload - maybe saved somewhere)

I realize this is not doable with javascript alone. So, I am open to a Java or Flash solution, and/or even a commercial solution (a drop-in java applet that I can add to our site).

So, is something like this available, or any other ideas on how I might approach this?

Thanks.

Comment: Flash can capture regions that are rendered by Flash Player, but not other parts of the page (or screen).

Answer (score 0):

Check out PhantomJS. http://www.phantomjs.org/

Actually it will re-render page on your server stack and you can save it as a png. Not same as your desired workflow, but definitely worth checking out.

Comment: had a look - not sure how that would solve my question. can you elaborate?

Comment: So here is what PhantomJS will help you with: You can provide a url of a page and it will render it in a png, svg or pdf format. [link](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart#Rendering) . Problem that you still need to solve is, how you get the coordinates of the region that needs to be captured and pass it on to the server where PhantomJS can do something with it. Again, it is not a complete solution but something that can be looked into. The people at "Bugmuncher" are doing same sort of functionality as you desire and are using PhantomJS on backend. [link](http://bugmuncher.com/)

Comment: yeah, except what if user wants to take a capture of a non-webpage?

Comment: Something like print screen? Can't think of anything else except taking screen capture, saving it as a file on machine and then uploading to your site. Or creating a desktop app either in silverlight or flex which talks to your web application.